# Android App is not shown when searched by name or package name on PlayStore

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin.android, google-play

I have published my application in Production on PlayStore 10 days ago. When I try to search by name (full/partial name search) or package name app isn't showing, but when I open with URL `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package_name` it's shown. I have all required release notes filled out (tags, description etc.) but still nothing.

What could be the reason for not showing in search results on PlayStore? Are someone has the same problem or any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: The same topic is open on Google Play Help (https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/15162444?hl=en) there isn’t any solution as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that it was bug with the Google search algorithm. My application was indexed after 15+ days from the date of release.

Full-text search working fine now, but if you want to do partial text search it seems that there is still a problem.

For everyone who has spaces in the application name adding "_" instead of " " will give you application first in search results.

> For example (full application name): ANDROID EXAMPLE NAME.
>
> Search Text: android_name

Answer (score 1):

If you are a developer and have just released your app, it can happen because Google Play needs some time to index your app to add it to search results. Try to search your app later (in 4-5 hours). E.g., for App Store it takes around 24 hours - 7days.

Eventhough your app got indexed, it must have a higher rank, so that when you serach partially, you can get the result. In order to increase your indexing ranking, you can give a read to [this](https://yourstory.com/mystory/9-ways-to-boost-your-app-ranking-to-top-in-google--iofk5ewasd)
.